# how to handle PHP notice in symfony2

Tags: symfony, handler, notice

I would like to find out how to manage notices thrown by PHP inside a symfony 2 project. I have a following code:

```
$this->login = $parameters['login'];
$this->password = $parameters['password'];
```

and a notice is thrown when the $parameters array doesn't have appropriate keys set. But symfony doesn't allow the code to go further and stops, showing the notice message but inside an exception:

```
Notice: Undefined property blah blah blah
```

in /vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Debug/ErrorHandler.php at line 67

```
    if (error_reporting() & $level && $this->level & $level) {
        throw new \ErrorException(sprintf('%s: %s in %s line %d', isset($this->levels[$level]) ? $this->levels[$level] : $level, $message, $file, $line));
    }
```

How to make symfony2 not throw an exception when just a notice is raised?

Comment: I agree that the best solution is to fix the notice. But in this case, sf2 project is not standalone, it relies on other systems which it integrates with (SOA), hence parameters may change quite often. I would like to be able to change this sf2 behavior.

Comment: did you try to change the reporting level with the php method error_reporting()?

Comment: @Cerad Well, catching notices can help to debug them, in order to avoid them from happening.