# Throw exception with php notices using Symfony 2.3

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling, symfony-2.3

Since I updated my project to Symfony 2.3 php notices don't throw exceptions any more.

I can try to access undefined indexes in arrays and a notice is displayed but no exception is thrown.

At first I tought I was confused and maybe this had been the behavior on prvious version. I found some question on stackoverflow that suggest otherwise.

[how to handle PHP notice in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839826/how-to-handle-php-notice-in-symfony2)

Is there anyway to make Symfony 2.3 throw exceptions on symfony2 notices?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found the answer. Here it is for any reference.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.3.md

Answer (score 3):

[Have a look](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/FrameworkBundle.php#L53) at the beginning of the `boot()` method in the FrameworkBundle:

```
public function boot()
{
    ErrorHandler::register(null, false)->throwAt($this->container->getParameter('debug.error_handler.throw_at'), true);
    // ...
}
```

Even if you register your own error handler in `AppKernel` (as I was doing), the FrameworkBundle overrides it. But you can configure the FrameworkBundle's error handler using the `debug.error_handler.throw_at` parameter, like so:

```
# in config.yml, for example
parameters:
    # ALWAYS throw exceptions for notices, warnings, etc.
    debug.error_handler.throw_at: -1
```

I'm not aware that this is documented anywhere.

Since PHP's notices and warnings often indicate serious programming errors (d'oh!), I like to always throw exceptions for everything, even in production.